how to resloved error for shopify unable to access
shopify when I created a custom app and I wanted to get cart data from a third-party website my store is "https://store.myshopify.com/cart.json" Cart data using API and node js then shows the error unable to access myshopify.com I will share my node code. now I am want to get the cart item in node js.
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');


const app = express();    
app.use(cors());

let apikey = '0520e894b0d93f2af3be7a07f3ef8yec';
let pass = 'shpat_d59f83a39d031d34ecbea8dqqq6f12ac';
let endpoint = 'cart';


let options = {
'method': 'GET',
'url' : `https://store.myshopify.com/${endpoint}.json`,
'headers': {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Allow': "GET",

  }
};


app.get("/", (req, reps)=>{

request(options,function(error, response){
    if(error) throw new Error(error);
    reps.send(response.body);
    console.log(response);
 });
});

app.listen(3900);
when I run code localhost:3900 in the browser there is an error. so I will share a screenshot below.

please give me any solutions.

You need to check the URL that has been requested in the network, because shopify is assuming that you are passing some malicious code. Also clear cache can enable cookies before making request. Also you need to enable yourself from admin for making further request calls.

@Yash Maheshwari, thanks dear for your reply, but the code is Shopify standard. because I am copying the above code Shopify docs, please give me code..

@Yash Maheshwari, for your information, when I get product api through get data then working. but cart API is not working. so I need to only how to Shopify store current cart item data and fetch data node js. If you have any ideas please share me. because I am fresher to create shopify app.
